# Testing whether pages can be fetched from two ports

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, asynchronous, http

I have an endpoint in my API which does a port test on 4455 and 4456 once a client GET's it. This is accomplished by requesting two web pages. The result will respond to the client with a JSON object:

```
{
    "4455": 200,
    "4456": 200
}
```

I have the following code

```
app.get(networkPfix + "/portcheck", (req, res) => {
        http.get('http://foo.com:4455/', (res, error) => {
            let status_code1 = res.status_code;
            http.get('http://foo.com:4456/', (res, error) => {
                let status_code2 = res.status_code;
                res.status(200).send({"4455": status_code1, "4456": status_code2});
            }).on("error", (err) => {
                let status_code2 = 0;
                res.status(200).send({"4455": status_code1, "4456": status_code2});
            }); 
            }).on("error", (err) => {
                let status_code1 = 0;
                http.get('http://foo.com:4456', (res, error) => {
                    let status_code2 = res.status_code;
                    res.status(200).send({"4455": status_code1, "4456": status_code2});
                }).on("error", (err) => {
                    let status_code2 = 0;
                    res.status(200).send({"4455": status_code1, "4456": status_code2});
                }); 
        }); 
    })
```

I'm quite new to Node, but surely there must be a neater way to achieve this, perhaps with less nesting?

To explain my code a little:

1. I need to test two webpages (one on each port)
2. Both webpages must be tested, even if there are errors
3. Timeouts would be nice, but I couldn't find a reliable way of stopping the callback
4. Return the JSON object to the client at the end